# "Add a Page" option missing from menu

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2013, permissions, publishing-site, groups

I have a user who is part of "Contribute" group. But when that user clicks on the wheel icon on top, then no "Add a Page" option is shown, although "Edit page" option is available.

Even if I give user "Full Control" permissions on this site, I still don't see "Add a Page" option. I have checked that both "Contribute" and "Full Control" have page adding permission.

I have tried it with different users but same problem. What could be the reason for that? This is very weird.

Only if user is part of site collection administrator, then "Add a page" option is shown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As usual this was SharePoint being SharePoint. I reset the IIS and now option is there. Really 3rd class product this SharePoint is.

Comment: Don't worry be happy ;)

Comment: Can't be happy as long as I am working on SharePoint :)