# Help For Adding Page to Site Collection Subsite

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise

i created a host named site collection under which i created a subsite with a project template. on the main portal page, there is an option to add a page to a site under the settings button, but when i navigate to the subsite, all i can do is edit a page. how do i add a new page to a subsite? i would think it would be trivial. on the other hand i am very new to sharepoint.

SharePoint 2013 Enterprise SP1, farm, windows server 2012 r2.

Comment: What is the template used for the subsite?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can directly call the create page as following

```
http://webapp/sitecollection/site/_layouts/create.aspx
```

Based on this [thread](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/90630/add-a-page-option-missing-from-menu) an IISRESET resolved the issue

Comment: thank you! when i clicked the Page link, sp asked me to install the wiki feature. not sure why since i don't want a wiki - just a plain old web page. however, it looks like this may work. thanks again!